# R leaflet does not render Map when using leafletProxy function with reactive Value

Tags: r, shiny

Am trying to create a leaflet Map that will update without being redrawn when user changes a selection.

I have a dataframe testDF that has names of towns, lat, lng and popn variables. I want the towns to be plotted on the Map and when user choses a town, the Markers should only be cleared by R not re-drawn. but when I run the App, it is run but Map is not rendered. I have failed to figure where error is and I need someone to help figure out.

Below is the code

```
library(shiny)

testDF \<- data.frame(Towns = c("Arua","Nebbi", "Moyo", "Kampala","Mbarara"),
lat = c(0.0113, 0.134, 0.1543, 0.1891, 0.12321),
lng = c(30.113, 30.551, 30.001, 31.008, 31.190),
popn = c(14000, 10000, 3000, 50000, 30000))

# Define UI

ui \<- fluidPage(

# Application title

titlePanel("Plot town population"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput(inputId = "towns", label = "select town", choices = testDF$Towns)),

      mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("TestMap",
                      height = "100vh")
        
      )
    )

)


# Define server logic

server \<- function(input, output, session) {
#define reactive variable
filterReact\<- reactive({
filter(testDF, testDF$Towns == !!input$towns)

    })
    
    #plot Map data
    output$TestMap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(filterReact()) %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers()
      
      
      mapModifier <-  leafletProxy(mapId = "TestMap", data =filterReact(), session)
      
      observeEvent(input$towns, {
        mapModifier %>%
          clearMarkers() %>%
          addMarkers()
      })
      
    })

}

# Run the application

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  `testDF$Towns == !!input$towns` is most likely incorrect.  `testDF$Towns == input$towns`. is most likely needed.  Also, if `input$towns` allows multple selections, you'll need ``testDF$Towns %in% input$towns`.  Equally important, you have nested reactives and observers.  That's (almost) always a recipe for disaster... Also, I assume your multiple `\<-`s are typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to give you what you want.  As I suggested in my comment, the key is to unnest your reactives and observers.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

testDF <- data.frame(Towns = c("Arua","Nebbi", "Moyo", "Kampala","Mbarara"),
                      lat = c(0.0113, 0.134, 0.1543, 0.1891, 0.12321),
                      lng = c(30.113, 30.551, 30.001, 31.008, 31.190),
                      popn = c(14000, 10000, 3000, 50000, 30000))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot town population"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "towns", 
        label = "select town", 
        choices = testDF$Towns
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("TestMap", height = "100vh")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filterReact<- reactive({
    filter(testDF, testDF$Towns == input$towns)
  })

  output$TestMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(filterReact()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$towns, {
    mapModifier <-  leafletProxy(
      mapId = "TestMap", 
      data =filterReact(), 
      session
    )
    mapModifier %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the contributions. it has worked. I have seen my biggest issue as you mentioned is nesting reactives and observers. Its taken me 3 days to try to figure out this with different set of codes :). AGAIN, THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to have helped.  My golden rule when writing Shiny apps is "never, ever, nest reactives and observers, in any combination".  Please accept my answer to indicate to others that your problem has been solved.